# Generating new values by combining two lists in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nlp, data-augmentation

I have a series of phrases that I tokenized. I then found the synonyms of each word and saved them in a dictionary with the word (i.e. token) as the key and a list of synonyms as the value. My goal is to generate new phrases by replacing each word with its synonyms and create new phrases.

For example, we have a phrase that has 3 tokens. The first token (limited) has 18 synonyms, the second token (social) has 4 synonyms, and the last token (support) has 16 synonyms. So theoretically we would have `18 * 4 * 16 = 1,152` new phrases by combining all 3 lists together.

```
phrases = ['limited', 'social', 'support']

dictionary = {
    'limited': ['express', 'limited', 'restrict', 'restrain', 'trammel', 'limit', 'bound', 'confine', 'throttle', 'circumscribe', 'specify', 'set', 'determine', 'define', 'fix', 'circumscribed', 'modified', 'special'],
    'social': ['sociable', 'social', 'mixer', 'societal'],
    'support': ['support', 'reinforcement', 'reenforcement', 'documentation', 'keep', 'livelihood', 'living', 'bread_and_butter', 'sustenance', 'supporting', 'accompaniment', 'musical_accompaniment', 'backup', 'financial_support', 'funding', 'backing']
}

new_phrases = [['express', 'sociable', 'support'], ['express', 'social', 'support'], ['express', 'mixer', 'support'], ['express', 'societal', 'support'], ..., [...]]
```

My attempt was to iterate through the items in each list but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how to combine these 3 lists together to generate something similar to `new_phrases` as shown in the code chunk above.

```
for word in phrases:
    print("\nthe word is:", word)
    print("list of synonyms is:", dictionary[word])
    print("the list has", len(dictionary[word]), "elements")
    for syn in dictionary[word]:
        print("a synonmy is:", syn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

new_phrases = list(itertools.product(*dictionary.values()))
```

```
>>> new_phrases
[('express', 'sociable', 'support'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'reinforcement'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'reenforcement'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'documentation'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'keep'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'livelihood'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'living'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'bread_and_butter'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'sustenance'),
 ('express', 'sociable', 'supporting'),
 ...
 ('special', 'societal', 'living'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'bread_and_butter'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'sustenance'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'supporting'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'accompaniment'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'musical_accompaniment'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'backup'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'financial_support'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'funding'),
 ('special', 'societal', 'backing')]
```